# How to detect if a window has been activated?

Tags: qt

Focus events don't work because they're not sent if you activate your window by clicking on its non-client frame. Also, if you click the internal components of the window THEY will get the focus event, not your window, but the window will still be activated, even if it wasn't active or focused before.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The event you want is `QEvent::WindowActivate`. Override `event()` to process it:

```
bool YourWidget::event(QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::WindowActivate) {
        // window was activated
    }
    return QWidget::event(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works in Python / PySide too. But when I override event() all my other events are blocked even if I call ignore() on them and return False. I can't use my GUI now, my buttons, text boxes and so on are never activated. Does anyone has an example of this?

Answer (score 11):

Qt provides several virtual event handling functions you can use. Since the activation of a window changes its state, you want to handle some change events:

```
void MyWidget::changeEvent(QEvent * e) {
    if(e->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange && this->isActiveWindow()) {
       // .. this is now the active window      
    }
}
```

#### References

- [`changeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent)
- [`isActiveWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#isActiveWindow-prop)

Comment: Not work if use Ctrl+Tab or click in taskbar on windows, however `QWidget::event` worked at all. Note: `isActiveWindow` is a good tip, thanks +1