# Why does starting a QProcess freeze the GUI in a QWidget subclass but not in a QLineEdit subclass?

Tags: qt, qprocess

I have a simple executable file (`english.exe`) that changes Windows' input language to English. I want to run this executable when the user interacts with various components of the GUI.

If I run the executable in the `focusInEvent` of `QLineEdit`, I get the expected behavior: the program runs, and there is no lag.

```
void MyLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);

    QProcess * switchInput = new QProcess(this);
    switchInput->start( "c:/english.exe");
}
```

I want to run analogous code when a particular widget is activated, for which [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721906/1447002). (In fact, I would like to use `focusInEvent` for a `QWebEngineView`, but [this resolved bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67852) notwithstanding, that event is never called; I am using Qt 5.12.6.) But with the following code, the GUI hangs.

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
    bool result = QWidget::event(event);
    if( event->type() == QEvent::WindowActivate )
    {
        // qDebug() << "QEvent::WindowActivate";
        QProcess * switchInput = new QProcess(this);
        switchInput->start( "c:/english.exe" );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using the `qDebug()` code, I'm only getting one "QEvent::WindowActivate" message.

What is the difference between the two calls? Is there an alternative solution?

---

**Edit:** Whatever solution I find may not be of general interest. The program I'm running is a command-line [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script (with contents `PostMessage, 0x50, 0, 0x0409,, A`) (no output or user interaction). For comparison I tried running `ipconfig.exe` (to take a command line program at random) and the problem goes away. So there must be something about the AutoHotKey script, or about AutoHotKey itself.

Comment: Did you try to move `QWidget::event(event);` call to the end of the `MyWidget::event()` function?

Comment: Yes, in fact at first I was calling `QWidget::event(event);` after my code, but then I moved it to the beginning of the function in an attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you hijack the eventloop in the latter case. did you try to "scheduling" it via 
`QTimer::singleShot(0, [&](){
QProcess * switchInput = new QProcess(this);
switchInput->start( "c:/english.exe" );}
);`
This way the starting of the process will be executed the next time the eventloop becomes active again. But consider it as a "hack"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Taron. I tried the code you suggested but it producted the same result.